# google mock - how to expect function to NOT be called with set of parameters

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Let's say you have `void Class::func(Type_t arg)`

I want to say

> this function can be called **except** with arguments `arg1` or `arg2`
>   or ... `argN`

Is this the correct way?

```
EXPECT_CALL(Class_MockObj, func(arg1)).Times(0);
EXPECT_CALL(Class_MockObj, func(arg2)).Times(0);
...
EXPECT_CALL(Class_MockObj, func(argN)).Times(0);
```

**FEEL FREE TO COME UP WITH A BETTER TITLE FOR QUESTION**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also write this using [AnyOf](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#composite-matchers):

```
EXPECT_CALL(Class_MockObj, func(AnyOf(arg1, arg2, .., argN))).Times(0);
```